# Random freezes kernel power

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, kernel

Hi everyone I see kernel power 41 (63) in computer management and my computer freezes every 10 minutes it keeps working only screen stuck. and it doesnt matter that I do anything even when it just start it can freeze. Here is my spec;

```
Processor Amd 9590 Eight core processor
ram : 16 Gb (15,9 usable)
Motherboard : asus crosshair v formula-z
HD 7870 series graphic
Samsung SSD
```

I just reinstalled the windows. I dont know what problem can be.Most of the time cpu is 40-57 degree
Please Help me to solve this...

I have disabled 4 cores and no more freezes any idea that core were broken or something ? or psu is not enough for eight core ? but now when I play games it shut downs(not freeze) I think its becuase of the heat but not sure I saw 80 degree

Comment: Out of interest, was the shop ever able to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: @James Thanks for asking.didnt have time to go to the store also  havent test my power supply yet. But I had sort of a fix. I have disabled 4 cores of cpu now it runs on 4 core (eight core default) and I'm not sure that its happening because of those cores(5,6,7,8) or my psu cant be enough for 8 core do u have any idea ? and after I disable 4 cores no problem so far

Answer (score 2):

There is conflicting information about whether your motherboard is compatible with your CPU. According to the [specs for the Asus Crosshair V Formula-Z](http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/CROSSHAIR_V_FORMULAZ/specifications/):

> Supports CPU up to 140 W

According to the [specs for AMD FX9590](http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=840&f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&f12=):

> Wattage: 220 W

The [CPU compatibility page](http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/CROSSHAIR_V_FORMULAZ/HelpDesk_CPU/) suggests that it is compatible but you need to be running **BIOS version 1403** or later. If your BIOS version is older than that then you should try upgrading it.

You haven't mentioned what PSU you have, but clearly you would need quite a powerful one to cope with that particular CPU.

Comment: Thanks for asking.didnt have time to go to the store also havent test my power supply yet. But I had sort of a fix. I have disabled 4 cores of cpu now it runs on 4 core (eight core default) and I'm not sure that its happening because of those cores(5,6,7,8) or my psu cant be enough for 8 core do u have any idea ? and after I disable 4 cores no problem so far

Comment: @Jackal: It may be that your PSU is more suited to high power graphics cards rather than high power CPU's. There are different rails for different voltages and the PSU output is given as a total of all of them. So you possibly need a different model PSU designed to work with AMD's most demanding CPU's. The store should be able to test if that is the issue. By disabling 4 of the cores, you have lowered the power requirements.

Comment: Well Then the solution is buying new psu but before I do that I will give psu and cpu to the store so maybe something wrong with psu. Hey thank you for your time mate at least we know what might be wrong